# Illegal characters in email when sent via smtp with Sendgrid on Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, sendgrid

I am importing a list of contacts from gmail and using a checkbox to select the returned emails and send an invitation out to users after they have been selected. When I look at the my logs the output has the email in the correct format and everything seems fine.

When I look at my email activity on Sendgrid I am seeing additional characters attached to the email address hence making it fail. I do not have any issues sending email with my other mailers using sendmail but this one seems to add these additional characters and I do not know where they are coming from.

Has anyone else seen this happening? Or have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Expected result
Email: test@gmail.com

Actual result
Email: "test@gmail.com"@i04-01

user_mailer

```
def invitation(email_addresses)
@host = ((Rails.env == "production") ? "http://www.test.com" : "http://localhost:3000")
attachments.inline['people.jpg'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/people.jpg")
#attachments.inline['people.jpg'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/Girl.jpeg")
email_addresses.each do |email|
  mail(:to => email, :subject => "Hello from test!")
end
```

end

user_controller

```
def import
#@user = User.find(params[:id])
#@users = User.find(session[:user_id])
begin
  @sites = {"gmail" => Contacts::Gmail, "yahoo" => Contacts::Yahoo, "hotmail" => Contacts::Hotmail}
  @contacts = @sites[params[:from]].new(params[:login], params[:password]).contacts
  @users, @no_users = [], []
  @contacts.each do |contact|
    #if u = User.find(:first , :conditions => @users.email = �#{contact[1]}� , :include =>[:user])
    if u = User.find(:first, :conditions => "email = '#{contact[1]}'")
      @users << u
    else
      @no_users << {:name => contact[0], :email => contact[1]}
    end
  end

  #if @contacts.save
  #end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => 'shared/_contact_list', :layout => false }
    format.xml { render :xml => @contacts.to_xml }
  end
end
```

end

```
def send_bulk_mail
name_email =[]
email_addresses=[]
names=[]
post=params[:post]
post.each do |k,v|
  if v=="1"
    name_email << k
  end
end
name_email.each do |n|
  email_addresses << n.split(",")[1]
end
UserMailer.invitation(email_addresses).deliver
```

end
Thanks

Comment: Could you post some code? It's hard to debug without it

Comment: Hello Mike I added the code that is doing the parsing. The most confusing part is the code works with gmail smtp configured but when I use sendgrid it puts the extra characters. Also, sendgrid does send emails if I do not use a form such as a notifier. When I look at the logs the additional characters to not exist.